# Spritekit physic different on iOS 7.x and iOS 8.x?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Why would the sprite kit physic be different on iOS 7.x vs iOS 8.x???

I have a simple spritekit scene... I have 2 static pins and in between I have sprites which are connected by a spring joint, dropping an object on this elastic rope would behave like a trampoline, everything was looking ok on iOS 7.x until I started testing on iOS 8.x. I've tested on similar devices, 2 iphones 5s and 2 ipod touch 5th gen with each 7 & 8, I'm getting the same fps, having the same number of nodes.

I have tried all kind of joint, factors, gravity, speed and every time I run this simple piece of code on different devices on 7.x I get a similar behavior, but if I run it on 8.x devices the 'elasticity' is different of the spring joint is different, stiffer on 7.x, the elastic will bend more on 8.x without anything on it but if you add several balls on it you can even see a greater effect on the 8.x devices. before I'm asked, here the skcene code

```
#define kFrequency 30.0f
#define kDamping 0.0f
#define kNodes 20

typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint32_t, CategoryMask)
{
    CategoryMaskBall = 1 << 0,
    CategoryMaskPin = 1 << 1,
    CategoryMaskElastic = 1 << 2,
    CategoryMaskBorder = 1 << 3
};

@implementation SimpleGameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor  blackColor];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -4.9);
    NSMutableArray *nodes=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:kNodes+2];
    SKSpriteNode *pin = [self addPin:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/4)];
    [self addChild:pin];
    [nodes addObject:pin];

    for( int i = 1; i<=kNodes; i++) {
        SKSpriteNode *elastic = [self addElastic:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2+i*(pin.size.width+1), self.size.height/4)];
        [self addChild:elastic];
        [nodes addObject:elastic];
    }
    SKSpriteNode *pin2 = [self addPin:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2+(kNodes+1)*(pin.size.width+1), self.size.height/4)];
    [self addChild:pin2];
    [nodes addObject:pin2];

    for( int i = 1; i<=kNodes+1; i++) {
        SKSpriteNode *nodeA = [nodes objectAtIndex:i-1];
        SKSpriteNode *nodeB = [nodes objectAtIndex:i];
        [self addSpringJointFrom:nodeA to:nodeB];
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        SKSpriteNode *ball = [self spawnBallAt:[touch locationInNode:self]];
        [self addChild:ball];
    }
}

-(SKSpriteNode*) spawnBallAt:(CGPoint)location
{
    SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"game"] textureNamed:@"circle"]];
    ball.position = CGPointMake( location.x, location.y);
    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.width/2];

    ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    ball.physicsBody.mass = 40.0f;

    ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryMaskBall;
    ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryMaskElastic ;
    ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =  0;
    ball.name = @"ball";

    return ball;
}

-(SKSpriteNode*) addPin:(CGPoint) location {
    SKSpriteNode *pin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"game"] textureNamed:@"pin"]];
    pin.position = location;
    pin.zPosition = 1;
    CGFloat offsetX = pin.size.width * pin.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat offsetY = pin.size.height * pin.anchorPoint.y;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGFloat side = pin.size.width;
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, side - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, side - offsetX, side - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, side - offsetX, 0 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 0 - offsetY);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    pin.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
    pin.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    pin.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    pin.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryMaskPin;
    pin.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    pin.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =  0;

    CGPathRelease(path);

    return pin;
}

-(SKSpriteNode*) addElastic:(CGPoint) location
{
    SKSpriteNode *elastic = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"game"] textureNamed:@"elastic"]];
    elastic.position = location;
    elastic.zPosition = 1;

    CGFloat offsetX = elastic.frame.size.width * elastic.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat offsetY = elastic.frame.size.height * elastic.anchorPoint.y;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGFloat side = elastic.size.width;
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, side - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, side - offsetX, side - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, side - offsetX, 0 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 0 - offsetY);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    elastic.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
    elastic.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    elastic.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    elastic.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    elastic.physicsBody.mass = 1.0f;

    elastic.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryMaskElastic;
    elastic.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryMaskBall;
    elastic.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =  0;

    CGPathRelease(path);

    return elastic;
}

- (void) addSpringJointFrom:(SKSpriteNode*) nodeA to:(SKSpriteNode*) nodeB {
    SKPhysicsJointSpring *joint = [SKPhysicsJointSpring jointWithBodyA:nodeA.physicsBody bodyB:nodeB.physicsBody anchorA:nodeA.position anchorB:nodeB.position];
    joint.frequency = kFrequency; //gives the joint some elasticity.
    joint.damping = kDamping; // 0.0f Will remove damping to create the 'pendulum'
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
}

@end
```

Comment: You said this happens on the simulator as well?

Comment: yes, but I have an old imac 2008 so I know performance is an issue on this one, I barely achieve 20fps, but when the physic is stable, the elastic bends exactly as on the ipod touch, so here it's not performance but pure physic I would guess.

Comment: Can you confirm all the devices are running the same iOS?

Comment: Andriko13, I had one test left which was to find same devices with different iOS versions! all my ipad mini/iphone were all on 7.x (didn't want to upgrade as it's my target version) and all ipod touch were on 8.x. I upgrade some of the the ipad/iphone to 8.x and can confirm that issue is with iOS version and not device! I've updated the question to reflect this.